# How to specify a port range using Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress in AWS PowerShell Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm using AWS Powershell Tools and AWS CLI.

I am able to add inbound rules to a security group using code like the following:

```
$IpRange = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.EC2.Model.IpRange
$IpRange.CidrIp = "102.196.30.33/32"
$IpRange.Description = "RDP"
$IpPermission = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.IpPermission
$IpPermission.IpProtocol = "tcp"
$IpPermission.FromPort = 2089
$IpPermission.ToPort = 2089
$IpPermission.Ipv4Ranges = $IpRange
Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId sg-9773d0bb -IpPermission $IpPermission

# Verify inbound rule has been correctly added
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-9773d0bb
```

However, if I try to add a second call to Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress and specify a port range, then the second call doesn't work:

```
$IpRange.Description = "FTP PASV"
$IpPermission.FromPort = 2025
$IpPermission.ToPort = 2030
Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId sg-9773d0bb -IpPermission $IpPermission

# Verify inbound rule has been correctly added
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-9773d0bb
```

No error is returned, however the rule is not added. Why not?

**UPDATE**
Some people have suggested using the AWS CLI authorize-security-group-ingress rule instead, however that returns an "Invalid JSON" error message if I add a description to the rule:
[image]

Usually something like this would indicate trouble with incorrect escaping of quotes, but I don't think it is. Here it is with double quotes around the string, and the internal double quotes escaped either using back-ticks, or double-double quotes:
[image]

Comment: If you are willing to just use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than PowerShell, you could just use: `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name <GROUP-NAME> --protocol tcp --port 3389 --cidr <CIDR-RANGE>`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I've had no luck getting authorize-security-group-ingress to work whilst also adding a 'description' to the rule, which is why I switched to AWS Powershell Tools. For example, the following command should work, but incorrectly returns invalid JSON (there's nothing wrong with the JSON): `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id "$SecurityGroupId" --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 2089, "ToPort": 2089, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "$UserIp/32", "Description": "RDP (Custom)"}]}]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in two parts:

PART 1: Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress.
Internally this command is modifying $IpPermission. If you try to change the $IpRange.CidrIp to a different address then you will see the error:

```
Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress : Cannot set values for both Ipv4Ranges and IpRanges properties on
the IpPermission type which is part of the request. Consider using only Ipv4Ranges as IpRanges has
been marked obsolete.
```

The solution is to reallocate $IpPermission.

```
$IpRange.CidrIp = "102.196.30.33/32"
$IpRange.Description = "FTP PASV"

$IpPermission = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.IpPermission
$IpPermission.IpProtocol = "tcp"
$IpPermission.FromPort = 2025
$IpPermission.ToPort = 2030
$IpPermission.Ipv4Ranges = $IpRange

Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId $sg -IpPermission $IpPermission
```

PART 2: For PowerShell (Windows) AWS CLI: you need to escape the double-quotes and surround the string with double-quotes.

Here is a working example:

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-12345678  --ip-permissions "[{\"IpProtocol\": \"tcp\", \"FromPort\": 2025, \"ToPort\": 2030, \"IpRanges\": [{\"CidrIp\": \"102.196.30.33/32\", \"Description\": \"FTP PASV\"}]}]"

Comment: Brilliant, both of those work.
With Part 2 though, I believe single quotes are required around the JSON string, not double quotes. Confusingly, I think it is AWS CLI that requires the backslash escaping, not Powershell (in Powershell escaping is done with back-ticks, not backslashes).

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy sticking with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), this worked for me:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxx --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 2025, "ToPort": 2030, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "102.196.30.33/32", "Description": "FTP PASV"}]}]'
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Unfortunately I receive an "Invalid JSON" error message with that exact same command. (I will add a screenshot to the question).

Comment: It worked for me on a Mac. I suggest you play around with the quote marks to get it happy on Windows. (Try changing them, excluding them, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, yes that was something I tried, but without success (see additional screenshot in the question). I'm pretty sure the string is correctly escaped, and is valid JSON, because I've tried just echoing the string to the console, and then opened the result in a JSON editor, and it all works fine.

Comment: I have been unable to find a syntax for Windows either. I notice that [Authorizing Inbound Traffic for Your Windows Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) uses a `$ip1` object -- I wonder if that would help?